# Glide 4.3.1 override and placeholder features not work

Tags: android, android-glide

I update my glide to 4.3.1 but all over I use glide the feature `.override()` and `.placeholder()` get `error: cannot find symbol method`.

```
Glide.with(this)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .override(200, 200)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_avatar_sign_up)
            .into(ivAvatar);
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You should use **[RequestOptions](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/migrating.html#requestoptions)**

Includes methods like:

- centerCrop()
- placeholder()
- error()
- priority()
- diskCacheStrategy()
- priority()
- override(100, 100)
- transforms()

**Sample code**

```
Glide.with(this)
     .load(YOUR_URL)
     .apply(new RequestOptions().override(100, 100).placeholder(R.drawable.placeHolder).error(R.drawable.error_pic))
     .into(imageview);
```

Comment: Just a note, I was not able to make it work with the property .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade()) on Glide 4.9.0

Comment: does it means that with the DrawableTransformation the override method doesn't work?

Answer (score 4):

Try This

```
Glide.with(this)
     .load(imageUrl)
     .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).override(200, 200))
     .into(ivAvatar);
```