# Glide.with(context).load("file://"+bitmapList.get(position)) showing error?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-glide

I using below code

```
Glide.with(context)
     .load("file://"+bitmapList.get(position))
     .override(153,160)
     .crossFade()
     .centerCrop()
     .dontAnimate()
     .skipMemoryCache(true)
     .into(holder.thumbnail);
```

> problem is that here   **.override(153,160)** this line showing compile
>   error like cannot resolve method *override(int,int)*

I got solution here: [glide:4.3.1 override and placeholder features not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47262017/glide4-3-1-override-and-placeholder-features-not-work) tried manyways it not working..please anyone help me

when i change like this

```
Glide.with(context)
     .load("file://"+bitmapList.get(position))
     .apply(new RequestOptions().override(153,160))
     .crossFade()
     .centerCrop()
     .dontAnimate()
     .skipMemoryCache(true)
     .into(holder.thumbnail); 

// I am getting error this line **.crossFade()**
```

Comment: Do `RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
                           requestOptions .override(250, 250)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> // I am getting error this line .crossFade()

[**`Cross fades`**](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/migrating.html#cross-fades)

Unlike **`Glide v3`** does NOT apply a cross fade or any other transition by default to requests. `Transitions` must be applied manually.

To apply a cross fade transition to a particular load, you can use:

```
import static com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade;

Glide.with(this)
            .load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CChZ.jpg?s=328&g=1")
            .transition(withCrossFade())
            .apply(new RequestOptions().override(100, 100)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background).centerCrop()
            )
            .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Thanks  sir..i need use this features **.crossFade()** please help me

Comment: @Mariyappan use this **`.transition(withCrossFade())`**

Comment: please update answer sir...when i change next line giving error to me

Comment: @Mariyappan in `Glide v4` if you want to use `.crossFade() ` than use **`.transition(withCrossFade())`**

Comment: @Mariyappan make sure you have imported this **`import static com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.drawable.DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade;`**

Comment: ok sir...i will add that line..i am using **compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'** this is correct sir

Comment: @Mariyappan no use latest **`compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'`**

Comment: @Mariyappan let me now in case in any query

Comment: your answer is working sir...i didn't change dependency sir

Comment: @Mariyappan glad it helped

Comment: @Mariyappan yes

Comment: .., Hi bro please help if you are https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52257225/suppressed-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-google-firebase-provider-fireb

Answer (score 1):

The correct implementation for crossFade in glide V4 should be:

```
Glide.with(this)
     .load(YOUR_URL)
     .transition(withCrossFade())
     .apply(new RequestOptions().override(153,160).placeholder(R.drawable.placeHolder).error(R.drawable.error_pic))
     .into(imageview);
```

Use this one.