# Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, google-cloud-firestore, build.gradle

My app works perfectly when you run it on API 23 - 27, but on API 21 & 22 it crashes with the following error:i tried lot still issuse is not resloved

This is the link having same issuse but it's not help me

[Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39825543/didnt-find-class-com-google-firebase-provider-firebaseinitprovider)

**Error**

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/kc.care.task-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/kc.care.task-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5358)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4926)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4860)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:183)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5667)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:962)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/kc.care.task-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/kc.care.task-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5343)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4926) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4860) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:183) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1545) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5667) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:962) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757) 
            Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                    ... 13 more
         Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

My **gradle** file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "kc.care.task"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 73
        versionName "7.4"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            multiDexKeepFile file('multidex-config.txt')
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { // this is for realm-db
        url 'http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile project(':materiallettericon')
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart-Realm:v2.0.2@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.felipecsl:gifimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.0'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.zoho:deskportalsdk:0.822'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.daimajia.slider:library:1.1.5@aar'
    compile 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: I visited lot of pages but nothing helped me..

Comment: Try this `implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'`

Comment: @NileshRathod i am checking bro...just mins i will come back

Comment: and use **`implementation`**  instead of `compile` because `compile` is deprecated

Comment: if i make that..i am getting lot of other error bro...That's a reason i using compile...what should i do

Comment: `Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0.` i am getting this compile time error bro when i add this  `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0`

Comment: check here https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/README.md