# Glide 4.3.1: placeholder() method is not working

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm using Glide 4.3.1 for loading Image. There are two conditions:

1. I use `into(ImageView)` , `placeholder()` works well
2. I use `into(new SimpleTarget() {...})`, `placeholder()` is not working

**This is my code of target:**

```
RequestBuilder drawableTypeRequest = Glide.with(MainActivity.this).asBitmap().load(uri);

drawableTypeRequest.apply(new RequestOptions().override(100, 100).placeholder(R.drawable.add_driver_photo)).into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition transition) {

                    imageView.setImageBitmap(resource);
                }
            });
```

**This is my working code**

```
 RequestBuilder drawableTypeRequest = Glide.with(MainActivity.this).asBitmap().load(uri);

 drawableTypeRequest.apply(new RequestOptions().override(100, 100).placeholder(R.drawable.add_driver_photo)).into(imageView);
```

And I find somebody ask similar question in stackoverflow: [glide:4.3.1 override and placeholder features not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47262017/glide4-3-1-override-and-placeholder-features-not-work), But it not my disk.

Can anybody solve my doubt? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a ten years android developer, I should tell you , if you use the first codes, Glide don't know which target the placeholder should place, you don't assign a imageView to the placeholder,
as we talked face to face, you should use ImageViewTarget instead of SimpleTarget, the constructor of ImageViewTarget has a param view, you can pass your imageView into there